# Laravel Select CASE relation exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a popular [fulltext search package](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence) installed on my application but now I need to adjust the relevance column if some relation exists. My problem is that the relations I want to check are very complex and impossible to replicate with joins so the solution like:

```
$results = MyModel::with('relation1', 'relation2')
                ->someComplexScopeRelation()
                ->distinct()
                ->search($string, $searchableColumns, true)
                ->orderBy('field', 'DESC')
                ->leftjoin('table2', function($q){
                    $q->on('table2.a','=','my_models.b');
                })
                ->select(array('field1','field2', DB:raw('CASE WHEN count(table2.id) > 0 THEN (relevance  + relevance * (count(table2.id) * 0.25)) ELSE relevance END AS relevance')))
                ->get();
```

is not possible because the relation with `table2` includes some complex conditions with other tables. Something like:

```
public function table2Relationship()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Table2')
                ->where('field', 'value')
                ->where(function($q){
                    $q->where('field', 'value')
                        ->orWhere('field', 'value');
                })
                ->where('field', 'value')
                ->whereHas('AnotherRelation', function($q){
                    $q->where('field', 'value');
                })
                ->whereHas('AnotherRelation2', function($q){
                    $q->where('field', 'value')
                        ->where('field', 'value');
                })
                ->where(function($q){

                    if(CONDITION)
                        $q->where('field', 'value')
                            ->orWhere('field', 'value');
                    else
                        $q->where('field', 'value')
                            ->where(function($q){
                                $q->where('field', 'value')
                                    ->orWhere('field', 'value');
                            })
                });
}
```

What I need is create multiple CASEs using my relations and if the condition/relation exists THEN I increment or decrement the value of column `relevance`, initially calculated by package above described and without duplicate code of declared relationship.

I need something like:

```
$results = MyModel::with('relation1', 'relation2')
                ->someComplexScopeRelation()
                ->distinct()
                ->search($string, $searchableColumns, true)
                ->orderBy('field', 'DESC')
                ->select(array('field1','field2'))
                ->addCaseSelect(function($q) {
                    $q->addCase(function($q) {
                                    $q->has('table2Relationship', function($q){
                                        $q->where('extra_conditions', 'value');
                                    }, '>=', 1);
                                }, 
                                DB::raw('(relevance + relevance * (count_table2Relationship * 0.25))'), //THEN
                                DB::raw('relevance') //ELSE
                        );
                    $q->addCase(function($q) {
                                    $q->has('table3Relationship', function($q){
                                        $q->where('extra_conditions', 'value');
                                    }, '=', 0);
                                }, 
                                DB::raw('relevance - 1'), //THEN
                                DB::raw('relevance') //ELSE
                        );
                }, DB::raw('relevance')) //AS
                ->get();
```

and should return something like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, 
(
    CASE 
        WHEN count(SELECT count(table2.id) FROM table2 WHERE ...) as count_table2Relationship >= 1 THEN (relevance + relevance * (count_table2Relationship * 0.5)) ELSE relevance 
        WHEN count(SELECT count(table3.id) FROM table3 WHERE ...) as count_table3Relationship = 0 THEN relevance - 1 ELSE relevance 
    END
) AS relevance FROM my_models WHERE ...
```

Anyone knowns a solution for this or a package that fills my needs?

After a couple hours of search I didn't found any package that leads with CASEs conditions (or IF/ELSE). With help I could be available to create a package for this...probably this will rocks!

Thanks!

Comment: Your examples here, at least for me, lack any real context and makes it difficult to understand exactly what the relationship structure is. Could you possibly provide an example which has less meaningless (a harsh word, but apt) identifiers? Things like `if (CONDITION)` are just not helpful.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. If you see, the relationship is not important. The important is that though Laravel's join methodology is not possible replicate all conditions of my relations. If I needed something like `SELECT field1, field2, CASE WHEN field1 > 2 THEN relevance + 1 ELSE relevance END FROM my_models WHERE... ` it's easy but my goal is get the same with the usage (without duplicate code) of one or more relationships. The same goal when we use `->whereHas('relationshipName', function(){})` but use in `SELECT CASE` condition